# Using a sum with a distinct in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns the data i'm looking for using a distinct, but when I SUM that data I get a wrong amount for a my hierachy point '4-2-0-0-5-2'. 4-2-0-0-5-2 has multiple rows so when I sum it, it doesn't add up correctly. What would be the best way to incorporate a distinct into a SUM statement.  Any help would be appreicated. Thanks.

First query :

```
     Select distinct B.Proj_Nbr,c.proj_cc,h.proj_cc, h.Proj_Hier, B.Proj_Nm, D.Fscl_Per, A.Amount
     from acct_bal a 
     inner join dim_proj b on a.dim_proj_id = b.dim_proj_id 
     inner join essbase_fcs.projects_hier_map c on c.proj_nbr = b.proj_nbr 
     inner join dim_per_mo d on d.dim_per_mo_id = a.dim_per_mo_id 
     Inner Join Dim_Acct F On A.Dim_Acct_Id = F.Dim_Acct_Id 
     Inner Join Dim_Org G On A.Dim_Org_Id = G.Dim_Org_Id 
     inner join essbase_fcs.projects_hier_map h on h.proj_cc = g.cost_ctr
     inner join dim_org g1 on c.proj_cc = g1.cost_ctr
     Where F.Fin_Lee_Nbr = 500 
     and c.proj_hier like '4-2-0-0-5-2%'
     And A.Dim_Scnro_Id = '45'
     And D.Fscl_Yr = '2014'
    And b.Proj_Nbr = '9005459'
    and fscl_per ='1'
```

RESULT of 2 rows:

```
9005459 0358080 0358080 4-2-0-0-5-2 Global Sales.com (iSell)    179777.09
9005459 0358080 0358057 4-2-0-0-5-5 Global Sales.com (iSell) 2257.3**
```

When I want to sum the data I use this query below. This gives me the two rows i'm looking for, but proj_hier 4-2-0-0-5-2 has the wrong amount because it has multiple rows.

```
 Select  B.Proj_Nbr,c.proj_cc, h.Proj_Hier, B.Proj_Nm, D.Fscl_Per, sum(A.Amount)
     from acct_bal a 
     inner join dim_proj b on a.dim_proj_id = b.dim_proj_id 
     inner join essbase_fcs.projects_hier_map c on c.proj_nbr = b.proj_nbr 
     inner join dim_per_mo d on d.dim_per_mo_id = a.dim_per_mo_id 
     Inner Join Dim_Acct F On A.Dim_Acct_Id = F.Dim_Acct_Id 
     Inner Join Dim_Org G On A.Dim_Org_Id = G.Dim_Org_Id 
     inner join essbase_fcs.projects_hier_map h on h.proj_cc = g.cost_ctr 
     inner join dim_org g1 on c.proj_cc = g1.cost_ctr
     Where F.Fin_Lee_Nbr = 500 
     and c.proj_hier like '4-2-0-0-5-2%'
     And A.Dim_Scnro_Id = '45'
     And D.Fscl_Yr = '2014'
    And b.Proj_Nbr = '9005459'
    and fscl_per ='1'
    group by B.Proj_Nbr,c.proj_cc,f.dim_acct_id, h.Proj_Hier, B.Proj_Nm, D.Fscl_Per
                    having Sum(A.Amount) <> 0 
                   Order By  H.Proj_Hier,  B.Proj_Nbr, D.Fscl_Per
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: the first row in your example has spaces in front of the number and the second row has asterisks after the number.  neither of these qualify as numbers.  are you attempting to sum a varchar column?  if so, try converting it to a number before summing it.

Comment: Oracle. I am summing the amount column. Ignore the astrericks and spaces, those were characters that got accidently added.

Answer (score 0):

Please Generalize the Question and then ask, If i understood your problem Here is solution:

General Query :

select sum(a.amountColumn) from your_table

group by agrrColumnName;

If i change your query :

Select distinct B.Proj_Nbr,c.proj_cc,h.proj_cc, h.Proj_Hier, B.Proj_Nm, D.Fscl_Per, **sum(A.Amount)**
     from acct_bal a 
     inner join dim_proj b on a.dim_proj_id = b.dim_proj_id 
     inner join essbase_fcs.projects_hier_map c on c.proj_nbr = b.proj_nbr 
     inner join dim_per_mo d on d.dim_per_mo_id = a.dim_per_mo_id 
     Inner Join Dim_Acct F On A.Dim_Acct_Id = F.Dim_Acct_Id 
     Inner Join Dim_Org G On A.Dim_Org_Id = G.Dim_Org_Id 
     inner join essbase_fcs.projects_hier_map h on h.proj_cc = g.cost_ctr
     inner join dim_org g1 on c.proj_cc = g1.cost_ctr
     Where F.Fin_Lee_Nbr = 500 
     and c.proj_hier like '4-2-0-0-5-2%'
     And A.Dim_Scnro_Id = '45'
     And D.Fscl_Yr = '2014'
    And b.Proj_Nbr = '9005459'
    and fscl_per ='1' **group by B.Proj_Nbr;**